# What are method-local classes used for?

Tags: java, inner-classes

```java
public void foo() {
    class Bar {
    }
    Bar b = new Bar();
}
```

I can't see any situation where a method-local class would be the best design choice. Have you ever used it? In what case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one usecase is, when you have a looping call to a method with interface-type as parameter, and the method is used just in that method. So instead of writing a separated class, You can define a method-local class. (anonymous class approach may work but if it is in loop, better create a class.)

```
interface A{ public int getValue();}
....
public void processValue(A a){}
....
public void showResults(){
    class B implements A{
        int getValue(){
            return value;
        }
    }
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
        processValue(new B())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've used one once or twice when I needed slightly differently parameterized versions of the same event listener attached to different swing components, but other than that I tend to prefer anonymous classes over named local ones.

A simplified example of this would be

```
public void attachListeners(final JLabel label) {
  class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    private String value;
    public ButtonListener(String val) { value = val; }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      label.setText(value);
    }
  }

  button1.addActionListener(new ButtonListener("value1"));
  button2.addActionListener(new ButtonListener("value2"));
}
```

Comment: Can you provide code snippet ? It's interesting!

Answer (score 0):

I've used it in a situation where I needed key-value pairs and my keys did not map to an existing class. I didn't want to make my "key class" available outside my method.

As an example example, the key could be composed of an `Employee` and a `Date`, and the values are booked hours for that employee on that date. In such a situation, it might look like this:

```
public void doExcitingCalculation() {
    class EmployeeDateKey {
        private Employee employee;
        private Date date;
        // Getters and setters ommited for brevity
    }

    Map<EmployeeDateKey, Double> bookedHours = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Empoyee, Map<Date, Double>> temp = fetchData();
    // This isn't a useful datastructure, so we remodel it
    for (Map.Entry<Employee, Map<Date, Double>> entry : temp.entrySet()) {
        for (Map.Entry<Date, Double> hours : entry.getValue().entrySet()) {
            bookedHours.put(new EmployeeDateKey(entry.getKey(), hours.getKey()), hours.getValue());
        }
    }

    // process data
}
```

Comment: But class EmployeeDateKey will not be visible in method fetchData(), won't it ? It causes to inline fetchData() method which will lead to giant method doExcitingCalculation().

Comment: this seems of no use as such. either list is of no use, or the method design is flawed(its doing no real work)

Comment: Good catch @Oleksandr.Bezhan, I rewrote the code a bit to better explain what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Using method-local classes can increase the readability of your code by keeping related parts together. As a contrived example, suppose you have a method that needs to create a thread to do something in the background:

```
class Test {
 void f() {
    // lots of stuff
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            doSomethingBackgroundish();
        }
    }).start();
    // lots more stuff
  }
}
```

Without method-local classes, you would have to either:

create a new named class inside Test to do the background processing, or
create a new named class in a separate source file to do the background processing.
Both these options can reduce the readability of the code by moving the related processing somewhere else in your source tree (maybe in the same source file, maybe in another source file entirely). Using a method-local class keeps the processing logic right where it is used.

This is certainly not applicable for all situations, but it can be very useful in a number of common situations. Such code is commonly used for GUI action listeners, which are very small classes that usually just relay action method calls from one place to another.